# how to add a clickable text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

Hi, I have a UI like the picture above, when the "forgot?" text clicked it will open another activity, this is an EditText view, Is there any way I can do to add the "forgot?" text and make it clickable?

Comment: how about showing code how you created it or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fit your needs:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:hint="Password"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et_password"
        android:text="Forgot?" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just set an `OnClickListener` to the `TextView` and you are good to go :)